# Ошибка компиляции Error:(39, 81) error: incompatible types: Listener<JSONObject> cannot be converted to Listener<String>

Tags: java, android

При компиляции возникает ошибка в строке `StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);`

Код:

```
public class PostActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://proforientator.info/?json=get_page&page_id=96";

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Gson gson;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
        gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        fetchPosts();
    }

    private void fetchPosts() {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    public final Response.Listener<JSONObject> onPostsLoaded = (  new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.i(PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), String.valueOf( response ) );

            Post[] posts = (gson.fromJson( String.valueOf( response ), Post[].class));
            //Log.i(PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), posts.size() + " posts loaded.");

            for (Post post : posts) Log.i( PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), post.content );
        }
    });

    private final Response.ErrorListener onPostsError = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(PostActivity.class.getSimpleName(), error.toString());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Укажите строку на которой возникает исключение.

Comment: StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка компиляции `incompatible types` говорит о несоответствии типов. Она может возникнуть при попытке присвоить полю/переменной/аргументу метода значения некорректного типа.

`StringRequest` это запрос строки, соответственно, слушатель должен иметь тип `Listener<String>`. У Вас же передается `onPostsLoaded` типа `Listener<JSONObject`. Об этом и говорит ошибка:

> error: incompatible types: Listener cannot be converted to Listener
>
> ошибка: несовместимые типы: Listener не может быть преобразован в Listener

Соответственно, есть два пути решения проблемы:

1. Изменить тип `onPostsLoaded` на `Listener<String>`:

   ```
   public final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = (new Response.Listener<String>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(String response) {
            //далее по смыслу
   ```
2. Изменить тип запроса на `JSONObjectRequest`:

   ```
   JSONObjectRequest request = new JSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);
   ```